# Liquibase script to delete table element based on other table element

Tags: liquibase

I am pretty unfamiliar with liquibase script.

1. I have two tables, tableA and tableB.
2. tableB contains elements that have a tableA_fk value. It means that they point to an element of tableA.
3. tableA contains elements that come always by group of two. One of the element point to the pk of the other element (relatedpk).
4. I want to delete all the elements of the tableA that have the field "someValue" equal to NULL and no element of tableB pointing to it.
5. The elements can be removed only by group of two

Example:

```
tableA:

+----+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| pk | name                | someValue | relatedpk |
+----+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | ElementA            |         1 |      NULL |
|  2 | ElementA            |         1 |         1 |
|  3 | ElementB            |      NULL |      NULL |
|  4 | ElementB            |      NULL |         3 |
|  5 | ElementC            |         3 |      NULL |
|  6 | ElementC            |         3 |         5 |
|  7 | ElementD            |      NULL |      NULL |
|  8 | ElementD            |      NULL |         7 |
|  9 | ElementE            |      NULL |      NULL |
| 10 | ElementE            |      NULL |         9 |
+----+---------------------+-----------+-----------+

tableB:

+----+------------------------------+-----------+
| pk | name                         | tableA_fk |
+----+------------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Value1                       |        2  |
|  2 | Value2                       |        3  |
|  3 | Value3                       |        9  |
+----+------------------------------+-----------+
```

In this example I want to remove ElementD with pk=7,8 from tableA.

Reason:

ElementA cannot be removed because

```
someValue != null
```

ElementB cannot be removed because

```
tableA_fk = 3 for element Value2 in tableB
```

ElementC cannot be removed because

```
someValue != null
```

ElementD can be removed because

```
someValue=NULL
No Element from tableB point to one of this two elements from tableA.
```

ElementE cannot be removed because

```
tableA_fk = 9 for element Value3 in tableB
```

Is it possible to implement somthing like that in a liquibase script?

In something like that

```
<changeSet id="remove-elements">
    <delete tableName="tableA">
    <where>ConditionToRemoveTheCorrectELements</where>
    </delete>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use the `<delete tableName>` tag, I would suggest that you just write the SQL required and use a `<sql>` or `<sqlFile>` change tag.